# VSTO C# add buttoms from folder on click

Tags: c#, dynamic, vsto, office-addins

I'm creating a word addin with VSTO and I need to dynamically add and remove buttons and groups.
What I'm trying to do is create a button, which you click after choosing a path (from browser), and will create a new group (or update existing one) containing a button correlated to each of the files in the folder.
The only missing piece I have is creating and deleting groups and buttons, which is definitely possible according to the internet, yet I couldnt find any guide to walk me through it.

Currently I have one button to insert (Doc1_Click) which inserts content of file selected from dropdown list, dropdown list which shows docx from selected path, and browse button (Browse0_Click) which allows the user to select folder.

I created 6 groups (one of my problems is that the number of groups is hard-coded and can't be changed by the user) which is why I have 2 arrays with 6 slots.

In my vision I would like to create for each group num of buttons each matching docx file from the folder, and correlate the num of sub folders (in main folder) to num of groups.

```
 public partial class Ribbon1
{
    String[] paths = new string[6]; //create list of paths correlated to each group 
    RibbonDropDown[] ddowns = new RibbonDropDown[6]; //create list of dropdown items for each group

    private void Ribbon1_Load(object sender, RibbonUIEventArgs e)
    {
        ddowns[0] = dropDown0;
        ddowns[1] = dropDown1;
        ddowns[2] = dropDown2;
        ddowns[3] = dropDown3;
        ddowns[4] = dropDown4;
        ddowns[5] = dropDown5;
        paths[0] = Properties.Settings.Default.path0;
        paths[1] = Properties.Settings.Default.path1;
        paths[2] = Properties.Settings.Default.path2;
        paths[3] = Properties.Settings.Default.path3;
        paths[4] = Properties.Settings.Default.path4;
        paths[5] = Properties.Settings.Default.path5;
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            actual_loader(i); // load manualy each group
        }
    }

    private void actual_loader(int num)
    {
       
        RibbonDropDownItem ddItem1;          
        ddowns[num].Items.Clear(); 
        DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(paths[num]);
        FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles("*.docx"); //Getting Text files
        foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
        {
            ddItem1 = Globals.Factory.GetRibbonFactory().CreateRibbonDropDownItem();
            ddItem1.Label = file.Name;
            ddowns[num].Items.Add(ddItem1); 
        }
    }

    private void Doc1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        GenericInsert(0);
        
    }


   //insert content from docx file into current position in file
    private void GenericInsert(int num)
    {
        if (ddowns[num].Items.Count != 0)
        {
            Word.Document doc = Globals.ThisAddIn.GetActiveDoc();
            doc.ActiveWindow.Selection.InsertFile(paths[num] + "\\" + ddowns[num].SelectedItem, "", false, false, false);
        }
        else
        {
        //print message box 
        }
    }

    private void Browse0_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        Browser(0);
    }

//allow user to choose folder
    private void Browser(int num)
    {
        using (var fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog())
        {
            DialogResult result = fbd.ShowDialog();

            if (result == DialogResult.OK && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fbd.SelectedPath))
            {
                switchFunc(num, fbd.SelectedPath); 
                paths[num] = fbd.SelectedPath; //update path array
                actual_loader(num);//refresh dropdown list 
         
            }
        }
    }

    //save new path to properties, couldn't find any other solution so I used a switch case 
    private void switchFunc(int num, String path)
    {
        switch (num)
        {
            case 0:
                Properties.Settings.Default.path0 = path;
                break;
            case 1:
                Properties.Settings.Default.path1 = path;
                break;
            case 2:
                Properties.Settings.Default.path2 = path;
                break;
            case 3:
                Properties.Settings.Default.path3 = path;
                break;
            case 4:
                Properties.Settings.Default.path4 = path;
                break;
            case 5:
                Properties.Settings.Default.path5 = path;
                break;
        }
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }

    private void dropDown0_SelectionChanged(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {

    }


}
```

}

Any help on the subject will be appreciated.

thanks

Comment: Can you post some code of what did you try so far?

Comment: I added some code of what I have so far. Currently what I have works fine but is not very dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot dynamically create and delete ribbon controls, but you can dynamically show and hide them as well as change their properties (caption, enabled/disabled, etc.)